# Как узнать высоту клавиатуры в Андроиде?

Tags: android, клавиатура

Как програмно узнать высоту выдвигаемой клавиатуры в Андроиде?

Comment: вы явно пытаетесь вставить какой-то костыль. Зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Не скажу, надо значит...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872724/get-android-keyboard-height вот тут пример, решали такую проблему

Comment: Ну ок, как установить высоту dropview от autocompletetextview, при которой бы клавиатура не перекрывала бы выпадающий список(dropview :), если он большой ?

Comment: Я же говорил, что костыль. А решение вот такое: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232622/1568530

Comment: Ха-ха, я делал с adjustResize , мне он не подходит. Ещё варианты бескостыльные знаете ? :)

Comment: Можете ограничить кол-во максимальных подсказок до такого, чтобы они точно не перекрывались клавиатурой

Comment: Вариант, но это в последнюю очередь...